# Como transformar array em string com php

Tags: php, array

**item 1** - Como faço isso

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 7
            [5] => 9
            .......
            .......
            [14] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 7
            [5] => 9
            ........
            ........
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            .....
            .....
```

**item 2** - virar isso (15 números separados por virgulas - cada conjunto em uma linha)

```
2,4,5,6,7,9,..1
2,4,5,6,7,9,...
...............
...............
```

sendo o **item 1** resultado do `print_r(combinacoesDe(15,$dezenas));` disso

```
$dezenas = array("2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "12", "15", "16", "18", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25");

function combinacoesDe($k, $xs){
        
        if ($k === 0)
            return array(array());
        if (count($xs) === 0)
            return array();
        $x = $xs[0];

        $xs1 = array_slice($xs,1,count($xs)-1);

        $res1 = combinacoesDe($k-1,$xs1);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($res1); $i++) {
            array_splice($res1[$i], 0, 0, $x);
        }
        $res2 = combinacoesDe($k,$xs1);
        
        return array_merge($res1, $res2);
        
 }

print_r(combinacoesDe(15,$dezenas));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É um `array` que tem posições e dentro de cada posição um outro `array`, exemplo

```
$dezenas = array("2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "12", "15", 
"16", "18", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25");

function combinacoesDe($k, $xs){

        if ($k === 0)
            return array(array());
        if (count($xs) === 0)
            return array();
        $x = $xs[0];

        $xs1 = array_slice($xs,1,count($xs)-1);

        $res1 = combinacoesDe($k-1,$xs1);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($res1); $i++) {
            array_splice($res1[$i], 0, 0, $x);
        }
        $res2 = combinacoesDe($k,$xs1);

        return array_merge($res1, $res2);

 }

$result = combinacoesDe(15,$dezenas);

foreach($result as $key => $value)
{
    echo implode($value,',');
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Exemplo Online](https://repl.it/JxnQ/9)

Comment: Ueh não é isso que você quer? @LeoCaracciolo quem gera esses dados é a função que você tem na sua pergunta

Comment: Ou você quer que cada uma caia uma linha? @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: exato, cada um em uma linha

Comment: uma linha 2,4,5,6,7,9,10,12,15,16,18,20,21,22,23  segunda linha 2,4,5,6,7,9,10,12,15,1‌​6,18,20,21,22,24  OU um separador diferente de virgula para cada grupo de 15 dezenas

Comment: Pronto @LeoCaracciolo,,,,

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a função `implode()`.

```
implode($array, ',');
```

Isso fará com que o array seja agrupado em uma string separando os valores por vírgula (você pode utilizar qualquer coisa como separador).

Exemplo:

```
$array = [1,2,3];
$i = implode($array, ',');
var_dump($i);
// Resultado 1,2,3

$i = implode($array, '@');
var_dump($i);
// Resultado 1@2@3
```